# Proving positive semidefiniteness using the Schur complement

Tags: matrices, positive-semidefinite, schur-complement

Let $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \ni C = C^\top \succ 0$. Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ with $\text{rank}(A) = m$, where $m \leq n$. How do I show that

\begin{equation}
C - CA^\top(ACA^\top)^{-1}AC \succeq 0
\end{equation}

holds?

Comment: What've you tried out so far?

Comment: Well, I thought that right-invertibility of matrix $A$ plays a central role, i.e. $ACA^\top (ACA^\top)^{-1} = I_m$ and similarly, $A^\top$ is left invertible. Then I get

$C - CA^\top (ACA^\top)^{-1}ACC^{-1}CA^\top (ACA^\top)^{-1}AC$

which still doesn't help me much...

Comment: Think about where the Schur complement comes from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $G$ is nonsingular, we have that $X\geq 0$ if and only if $G^TXG\geq 0$.
Hence
$$
X:=C-CA^T(ACA^T)^{-1}AC\geq 0
$$
if and only if $C^{-1/2}XC^{-1/2}\geq 0$ ($G:=C^{-1/2}$), that is,
$$
I-B^T(BB^T)^{-1}B\geq 0,
$$
where $B:=AC^{1/2}$. Now note that $P:=I-B^T(BB^T)^{-1}B$ is an orthogonal projector ($P=P^T$, $P^2=P$) and all orthogonal projectors are positive semidefinite:
$$x^TPx=x^TP^2x=x^TP^TPx=(Px)^T(Px)\geq 0$$ for any vector $x$.